# Weblogic WSLT in modular python script

Tags: python, weblogic, weblogic-10.x

I'm creating a script to automate creation of JMS resources in a declarative way using `wslt.sh`. This way I just need to run `wslt.sh create_resources.py planned_resources.properties`

create_resources.py imports another module of mine `import include.jms as nmjms`. This include/jms.py calls `cd` and `cmo` of the WSLT.

The problem is, calling `cd` doesn't change the state of `cmo` in the jms.py module, so that I can't execute context related commands on `cmo` after the `cd` invocation. This is frustating...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create a module wl.py with the folowing code :

```
# Caution: This file is part of the command scripting implementation. 
# Do not edit or move this file because this may cause commands and scripts to fail. 
# Do not try to reuse the logic in this file or keep copies of this file because this 
# could cause your scripts to fail when you upgrade to a different version.
# Copyright (c) 2004,2014, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

"""
This is WLST Module that a user can import into other Jython Modules

"""
from weblogic.management.scripting.utils import WLSTUtil
import sys
origPrompt = sys.ps1
theInterpreter = WLSTUtil.ensureInterpreter();
WLSTUtil.ensureWLCtx(theInterpreter)
execfile(WLSTUtil.getWLSTCoreScriptPath())
execfile(WLSTUtil.getWLSTNMScriptPath())
execfile(WLSTUtil.getWLSTScriptPath())
execfile(WLSTUtil.getOfflineWLSTScriptPath())
exec(WLSTUtil.getOfflineWLSTScriptForModule())
execfile(WLSTUtil.getWLSTCommonModulePath())
theInterpreter = None
sys.ps1 = origPrompt
modules = WLSTUtil.getWLSTModules()
for mods in modules:
    execfile(mods.getAbsolutePath())
jmodules = WLSTUtil.getWLSTJarModules()
for jmods in jmodules:
    fis = jmods.openStream()
    execfile(fis, jmods.getFile())
    fis.close()
wlstPrompt = "false"
```

Next, import this module in your jms.py module and call wlst commands like this : wl.cd('...')

Comment: You saved my day! For my case it should be http://northernserve.ca/downloads/Oracle/Middleware/wlserver_10.3/common/wlst/modules/wlstModule.py

Comment: The above script is generated by WLST using `wls:/(offline)> writeIniFile("wl.py")` The process is explained in the Oracle documentation. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24491/using_wlst.htm#WLSTG153